Where does Microsoft Snipping Tool save video files?
Suppose I make a video with the Snipping Tool. Where does it put the file? I have difficulty finding the files after I record them.

This question is similar to: How can I change the default location Snipping Tool auto-saves screenshots to?. Not exactly a duplicate but the Q&A answers your question here in full, I suppose.

By default it is saved in C:\Users%USERNAME%\Videos\Screen Recordings. F.i. if your user name is John it is C:\Users\John\Videos\Screen Recordings
